# Animation crashes program COCOS2D

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, animation, cocos2d-iphone

Im trying to make a game in cocos2d. I have the version before they depriciated ccspritesheet and all those things. Im trying to get a ship to explode. its a ccsprite, and i run this code in the - (id)init

```
        CCSpriteSheet * sheet = [CCSpriteSheet spriteSheetWithFile:@"Explode.png"];

    [self addChild:sheet];

    NSMutableArray * explosionFrames = [NSMutableArray array];

    int spriteWidth = 256;

    for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
        [explosionFrames addObject:[CCSprite spriteWithSpriteSheet:sheet rect:CGRectMake(i*spriteWidth, 0, spriteWidth, 100)]];
    }

    CCAnimation * animation = [CCAnimation animationWithName:@"explode" delay:0.1f frames:explosionFrames];

    CCAnimate * explosion = [CCAnimate actionWithDuration:.5f animation:animation restoreOriginalFrame:NO];

    [self runAction:explosion];
```

when i run the program it just crashes straight off saying

```
-[CCSprite rect]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x54484f0
```

in the console.

i have no idea whats going on. this is my 1st time trying to animate in cocos and im probably being an idiot. any help is almost as awesome as u. Thanks!

i cant upload the sprite sheet im using because i am new and it wont let me and that makes sense. but its a 1792 × 100 png

Comment: Tickets to the clue train are $10. Get on board!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The deprecated **CCSpriteSheet** has been replaced by **CCSpriteBatchNode**. But anyway to create a sprite from a rect of the spritesheet, you should call  [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:sheet.texture rect:yourRect], where sheet is your **CCSpriteBatchNode**.

The following code should work for cocos2d 2.x. For a good tutorial on animation using spritesheets in cocos2D, check out: http://www.raywenderlich.com/1271/how-to-use-animations-and-sprite-sheets-in-cocos2d

```
    // Create a batchnode from your spritesheet file
    CCSpriteBatchNode *sheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"Explode.png"];
    [self addChild:sheet];

    int spriteWidth = 256;

    // Create the sprite starting with the first frame.
    CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:sheet.texture rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, spriteWidth, 100)];
    CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    sprite.position = ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);

    // Create the array the holds the animation frames
    NSMutableArray * explosionFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
    {
        [explosionFrames addObject:[CCSpriteFrame frameWithTexture:sheet.texture rect:CGRectMake(i*spriteWidth, 0, spriteWidth, 100)]];
    }

    // Create the animation from those frames.
    CCAnimation * animation =[CCAnimation animationWithSpriteFrames:explosionFrames delay:.2f];
    CCAnimate * explosion = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:animation];

    // Start running the animation
    [sprite runAction:explosion];

    // Add the explosion as child of spritesheet
    [sheet addChild:sprite];
```

Comment: can you tell me what is wrong with my code? im really confused. thanks for answering!